# unable to install programs

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04, dpkg

then i try to install somthing with apt-get install i get an error 
i have trayed install mono

```
dpkg: error processing package php7.3-bz2 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 php7.2-common
 php7.3-common
 php7.3-xmlrpc
 php7.2-curl
 grub-pc
 php7.3-dev
 php7.3-curl
 php7.2-mbstring
 php7.3-opcache
 php7.3-xml
 php7.2-readline
 php7.3-gd
 php7.2-cli
 php7.3-mysql
 php7.3-cli
 php7.2-json
 php7.2-cgi
 php7.3-readline
 php7.3-fpm
 php7.3-intl
 php7.3
 php7.2-opcache
 php7.2-mysql
 php7.2-gd
 php7.2-dev
 php7.2-xml
 php7.3-zip
 php7.2-xmlrpc
 php7.2-fpm
 php7.3-mbstring
 php7.2-zip
 php7.3-json
 php7.3-phpdbg
 php7.3-bz2
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

link to the entirer error messege
https://pastebin.com/1GgmK9v4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mono-devel is already the newest version (6.8.0.105-0xamarin3+ubuntu1804b1).`

So the package you were installing is already installed properly, however you have other packages that are `not fully installed`, as the error states.

You can try to see which process uses via

`sudo fuser -v /var/cache/debconf/config.dat`

and probably kill the process with `kill -9 PID_ID`

And then use:
`apt install -f`

to resolve these dependencies.